# How to create buttons and data picker using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display an array of json data into a table. In each set of records I want add one datepicker and one button.
Now If I click on that button I want the datapicker to be changed to just a Input field.

Example - data -- [
                    {
                    "name": "sourabh",
                    "phone": "255888888"
                    },
                    {
                    "name": "sourabh",
                    "phone": "255888888"
                    }];

In table it should display like this and cliking on update should change datapicker to input box. 
[image]

Comment: It's because your table data is being loaded after the DOM is loaded. Therefore, you need to re-init your datepicker AFTER the data is loaded, OR use a different binding method such as `live()`

Comment: How can I re-intialize it? And If I click on the button the associated datapicker should be changed to input box. :(

Answer (score 0):

use method in the end of ready function

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var status = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "sourabh",
            "phone": "811880",
            "email": "sourabhgrg713@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "sourabh",
            "phone": "255888888",
            "email": "Sourabhgrg713@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "sourabh",
            "phone": "255888888",
            "email": "Sourabhgrg713@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "sourabh",
            "phone": "255888888",
            "email": "Sourabhgrg713@gmail.com"
        }];

    var len = status.length;
    var x = '<input type="date" class="dt datepicker">';
    var y = '<button class="make waves-effect waves-light btn" type="button">';
    data = "";
    if (len > 0) {

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            data = data + "<tr><td>" + status[i].name + "</td><td>" + status[i].phone + "</td><td>" + x + "</td><td>" + y + "</td><tr>";
        }

    }

    $("#mytable tbody").append(data);
    
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js" ></script>

<table id="mytable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th data-field="id">Contact Name</th>
          <th data-field="phone">Phone</th>
          <th data-field="Data"> Data</th>
          <th data-field="Action"> Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>


    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Vlad, I am using materialize and pickadate exist there.

Comment: sorry. didnt know that.. eddited
need to add normalize css and it should be ok I think.

Just init datepicker after you append html.

Comment: @scripter, please edit your question and add all pertinent information/requirements.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Done that.